# If a, b, c, and d lie in the same plane, then $(a \times b) \times (c \times d) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ lie in the same plane, then $(a \times b) \times (c \times d) = 0$

I can't really see a way to prove this other than

if $(a \times b)$ is an orthogonal vector $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $(c \times d)$ is an orthogonal vector $u$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then cross product of $u\times v$ has to lie in the original plane as the cross product is perpendicular to both planes

As you can see this isn't very general or formal for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n =a \times b$. $n$ is perpendicular to the plane. Let $m = c\times d$. $m$ is perpendicular to the plane as well. Then $n$ is parallel to $m$. Then...?

Answer (score 1):

The way I remember it is that $(\vec a \times \vec b)$ will produce a vector $\vec v$ which will be orthogonal to the vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$, which in this case will be perpendicular to the plane.

However in this case you also have $(\vec c \times \vec d) = \vec u$ which would also be perpendicular to the plane.

Therefore $(\vec u \times \vec v) = \lVert u \rVert \lVert v \rVert \sin(\theta)$, since $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are perpendicular to the plane, you'll either have $\theta = 0$ or $\theta = \pi$, showing that $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are either parallel or in opposite directions. So in the end you
ll finally have $(\vec a \times \vec b) \times (\vec c \times \vec d) = \vec u \times \vec v = \lVert u \rVert \lVert v \rVert \sin(\theta) = 0$

Comment: They are either parallel or they have an 180 angle between them. Since the perpendicular vector can go "down" the plane. No?

Comment: Yes, but it would still yield to zero since you'll have $\theta = \pi$. I should have added that to my answer sorry.

Comment: No problem, just want to make sure the answer is complete. +1